# How to update EC2 instance state with boto3 resource

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm writing a python function with boto3 that starts an EC2 instance and then needs to wait until the instance is running.  I understand how this works with a client, but I'd like to do it with a resource.
I tried using a for loop checking `instance.state`, but the state never updates.  So I guess I'm looking for some sort of refresh method.

I see there is a `wait_until_running()` [waiter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.wait_until_running), but this is locked to a 15 second delay.  I want to poll more often than that.

Comment: Are you sure you need to check more often than every 15 seconds? This interval seems reasonable considering the delay needed to start an EC2 instance. The expected gain in time by pulling more often in quite low.

Comment: I want it as fast as possible because I'm trying to SSH into the machine right away.  I could add a time.sleep(5) before the waiter to reduce server load if that's an issue. If it's up after 16 seconds, that would be a long time to wait.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the WaiterConfig setting also works for a resource, even though it's documented only for a client.
`wait_until_running(WaiterConfig = {'Delay': 2})`

After the waiter, you still have to run `Instance.reload()` to update the state.

Comment: What happen if don't run `Instance.reload()`? I can't find difference running that or not

Comment: If you don’t reload I think some properties will be inaccurate such as `public_ip_address`

Comment: When I do this **Instance Start -> wait_until_running -> (without reload) -> print(instance.public_ip_address)**, there's no problem(IP address correct with IP can be seen at AWS EC2 console)